# restangular PUT ignoring ID param

Tags: angularjs, restangular

So I have the following angular 1.3 code

```
Restangular.one('user',270).get().then(function(existingUser){
existingUser.password = "foo";
existingUser.put();
});
```

Which grabs the user at http://api.dev/user/270 fine, however, the existingUser.put(); makes a PUT request to http://api.dev/user, ignoring the ID.

Changing to

```
 Restangular.one('user/270').get().then(function(existingUser){
    existingUser.password = "foo";
    existingUser.put();
    });
```

works fine, however looking at the examples on the Restangular homepage, it appears my original code should also work fine. Any pointers to whats going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Solved, issue was related to the existingUser being returned having a existingUser.userID attribute rather than a existingUser.id attribute.

Its this attribute that restangular seems to use for future post/put requests, rather than the id passed into the one() command.

Comment: Thank's bro, you saved my life. I was investigating it for two days... Thank you!